# vsftpd: permit the user see only her/his home directory

Tags: users, vsftpd

I have just installed `vsftpd` and created a new user: `sudo useradd new_user -m`. Then I have uncommented the line below at `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

to permit the user to see (access) only her/his home directory.

I have then restarted vsftpd.

**The problem**: when I connect through `ssh` or a `ftp` client using that new user, the new user can see (access) every computer directories, and I expected she/he to see **only her/his home directory**.

Im on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Vsftpd has nothing to do with ssh. Were you trying an ftp client or an sftp client? Very different protocols

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
passwd_chroot_enable=yes
```

> passwd_chroot_enable
>
> If enabled, along with chroot_local_user , then a chroot() jail location may be specified on a per-user basis. Each user's jail is derived from their home directory string in /etc/passwd. The occurrence of /./ in the home directory string denotes that the jail is at that particular location in the path.

Also note AFAIR vsftp has to run as root to let any chroot settings work!

See also

> run_as_launching_user
>
> [...] Specifically, vsftpd does not / cannot use chroot technology to restrict file access when this option is set (even if launched by root). [...]

Comment: thanks, but doesn't work. I stil can access every directories with that user.

Comment: Have you checked my last edits? Is vsftp running as root?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies but I don't have an unmodified copy of /etc/vsftpd.conf from Ubuntu 14.04 handy for comparison. Perhaps this will help.

If you have `chroot_list_enable` activated, you may provide a list of local users who are placed in a chroot() jail in their home directory upon login.

**The meaning is slightly different if chroot_local_user is set to YES**. In this case, the list becomes a list of users which are NOT to be placed in a chroot() jail. By default, the file containing this list is /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list, but you may override this with the `chroot_list_file` setting, Excerpt from man page for that seting is below.

`chroot_list_file`

The option is the name of a file containing a list of local users which will be placed in a chroot() jail in their home directory. This **option is only relevant if the option `chroot_list_enable` is enabled. If the option `chroot_local_user` is enabled, then the list file becomes a list of users to NOT place in a chroot() jail.**

```
Default: /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

Sources:

https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html

https://linux.die.net/man/5/vsftpd.conf